# how to tidy a word separated by underscores in the character vector

Tags: r

I have a very quick question on how to change the character vector below(1st to 2nd one)

```
data <- c("A_B", "A_C", "A _D", "D_ C", "C _C", "D_ D")
data <- c("A_B", "A_C", "A_D", "D_C", "C_C", "D_D")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[:blank:]]` works also in `gsub` to get rid of white space

```
data <- c("A_B", "A_C", "A _D", "D_ C", "C _C", "D_ D")


data2 <- sapply(data,gsub,pattern='[[:blank:]]',replacement='',USE.NAMES = F)

data2
```

**output;**

```
'A_B''A_C''A_D''D_C''C_C''D_D'
```

Comment: The `sapply` is not necessary (or really recommended) since `gsub()` is already vectorized over the input. you can just use: `data2 <- gsub(pattern='[[:blank:]]', replacement='', data)`

Comment: yes you are right, it's just an unnecessary habit :)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `gsub` with a regex lookaround to remove one or more spaces (`\\s+`) that precedes or succeeds a `_`

```
gsub("\\s+(?=\\_)|(?<=_)\\s+", "", data, perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "A_B" "A_C" "A_D" "D_C" "C_C" "D_D"
```

---

If the spaces are only present before or after the underscore, we can also do a non-specific matching of one or more spaces (if it is a single occurrence, `sub` is also enough)

```
gsub("\\s+", "", data)
[1] "A_B" "A_C" "A_D" "D_C" "C_C" "D_D"
```